# Are there any services that will update Google Latitude from Yahoo Fire Eagle?

Tags: yahoo, geolocation, google-latitude

I'm looking for a web application that will update my Google Latitude location every time I update my Yahoo Fire Eagle location. I checked the Fire Eagle [application gallery](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/gallery) and didn't find anything that would do this.

Answer (score 1):

## IFTTT

For anything that requires cross-app integration, I use **[IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/)** which stand for **IF This, Then That**. It allows you to create **[recipes](https://ifttt.com/wtf)** which are basically a set of actions consisting of a **Trigger** and an **Action** (to be taken on Trigger) for **[Channels](https://ifttt.com/channels)** which are apps that it supports (like Facebook or Gmail or WordPress or Date and Time, you get the idea).

As for your particular case, they don't have a Channel for **[Google Latitude](https://latitude.google.com)** of **[FireEagle](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/)** yet. You can **[contact](https://ifttt.com/contact)** them, though.

---

### FireEagle -> FourSquare

Okay, so I thought about it and came upon the idea of using a middleman. You can use **[FireCheckIn](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/gallery/app/V26MSHhx4WmyqU3KrZQR)** to integrate **[FireEagle](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/)** and **[FourSquare](http://foursquare.com/)**. That was easy.

### FourSquare -> Latitude

While IFTTT *does* have a for FourSquare, it doesn't for Latitude, so it can't be of any help. After Googling, I found **[this post](http://www.slideshare.net/Jean696Perez/how-you-can-link-and-fasten-google-latitude-with-foursquare)** which tells you how to connect the two.

If that doesn't work, you can use IFTTT, though in a different way. You can use the **[FourSquare Channel](https://ifttt.com/foursquare)** to output the check-ins to a text file in Dropbox or a message in Evernote, from where you can search for integration into Latitude.

---

### List of Channels

While isn't relevant to your question, I am proud that I came up with the code to extract this within 20 minutes considering I'm a newbie to JS:-

For a full list of IFTTT's currently supported channel, here you go:-

- [App.net](https://ifttt.com/appdotnet)
- [bitly](https://ifttt.com/bitly)
- [Blogger](https://ifttt.com/blogger)
- [Box](https://ifttt.com/box)
- [Boxcar](https://ifttt.com/boxcar)
- [Buffer](https://ifttt.com/buffer)
- [BuzzFeed](https://ifttt.com/buzzfeed)
- [Craigslist](https://ifttt.com/craigslist)
- [Date & Time](https://ifttt.com/date_and_time)
- [Delicious](https://ifttt.com/delicious)
- [Diigo](https://ifttt.com/diigo)
- [Dropbox](https://ifttt.com/dropbox)
- [Email](https://ifttt.com/email)
- [Evernote](https://ifttt.com/evernote)
- [Facebook](https://ifttt.com/facebook)
- [Facebook Pages](https://ifttt.com/facebook_pages)
- [Feed](https://ifttt.com/feed)
- [ffffound!](https://ifttt.com/ffffound)
- [Flickr](https://ifttt.com/flickr)
- [Foursquare](https://ifttt.com/foursquare)
- [Gmail](https://ifttt.com/gmail)
- [Google Calendar](https://ifttt.com/google_calendar)
- [Google Drive](https://ifttt.com/google_drive)
- [Google Reader](https://ifttt.com/google_reader)
- [Google Talk](https://ifttt.com/google_talk)
- [HootSuite](https://ifttt.com/hootsuite)
- [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/ifttt)
- [Instagram](https://ifttt.com/instagram)
- [Instapaper](https://ifttt.com/instapaper)
- [Last.fm](https://ifttt.com/lastfm)
- [LinkedIn](https://ifttt.com/linkedin)
- [Phone Call](https://ifttt.com/phone_call)
- [Pinboard](https://ifttt.com/pinboard)
- [Pocket](https://ifttt.com/pocket)
- [Pushover](https://ifttt.com/pushover)
- [Salesforce Chatter](https://ifttt.com/salesforce_chatter)
- [SMS](https://ifttt.com/sms)
- [SoundCloud](https://ifttt.com/soundcloud)
- [Stocks](https://ifttt.com/stocks)
- [Storify](https://ifttt.com/storify)
- [Svpply](https://ifttt.com/svpply)
- [Tumblr](https://ifttt.com/tumblr)
- [Twitter](https://ifttt.com/twitter)
- [Vimeo](https://ifttt.com/vimeo)
- [Weather](https://ifttt.com/weather)
- [WeMo Motion](https://ifttt.com/wemo_motion)
- [WeMo Switch](https://ifttt.com/wemo_switch)
- [WordPress](https://ifttt.com/wordpress)
- [Yammer](https://ifttt.com/yammer)
- [YouTube](https://ifttt.com/youtube)
- [Zootool](https://ifttt.com/zootool)

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that I already looked there. Unfortunately, even though they have some things like Foursquare on  there, it doesn't do anything with locations yet.

Comment: @pidge You can request them to do so, though. They've been adding a lot of new stuff lately. If there's no other answer, can you still accept mine, please?

Comment: OK, _now_ I should definitely get the bounty :)

Comment: Well, I should have checked before I awarded the bounty, but I think your directions go the wrong way (from Latitude to Fire Eagle). And FireCheckIn doesn't exist any more. 'A' for effort though?

Comment: @pidge Well, the repo's still there on GitHub ( https://github.com/johl/FireCheckIn ), but sorry if I wasn;t of any help. I don't really use any of the services. Why can't you just use one?